# code set background color for Anchorpane in FXML document

Tags: javafx, netbeans, scenebuilder

I am creating a small application in javafx. I want to set a background color so following is my FXML code .. how I need to set background color

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane"  prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="javafxapplication1.FXMLhomepageController">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="lb1" layoutX="139.0" prefHeight="109.0" prefWidth="343.0" text="home page" textAlignment="JUSTIFY" textFill="#355680">
         <font>
            <Font size="68.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Comment: i tried bro but not get the answer..

Comment: Are you using `Scene Builder`?

Comment: yes I am using  Scene Builder

Comment: I updated the answer. I would suggest you learn about `CSS` and use a stylesheet instead. In the answer below, I do not show how to use a `CSS` stylesheet.

Comment: yes sure I tried for a small project .. I am surely study the course

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is an example:

```
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: blue;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" />
```

If you are using `Scene Builder`, you should learn how to use this section under `Properties`:

[image]

You can also use a `CSS` stylesheet to accomplish this.